# Automated telnet test on IBM AS400

Tags: automated-tests, ibm-midrange, telnet

Does anyone know if it is possible to run an automated Telnet test (to a specific port) on an IBM AS400 platform in batch?

Ideally the output of the telnet test should be written to QsysOpr or a file in the IFS if possible.

The target platform is v7r3.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: So you want run the test on the IBM i?  Or on a PC to the IBM i?

Comment: Run the test on IBM-I, telnet'ing to an IP on a specific port.

Comment: The only approach I can think of is to create a shell script on a Linux Server, which SSH's to the IBM-I and then performs a telnet to the specified IP.  But looking for a cleaner way, the less steps the better.

Comment: does it have to be initiated from a PC, or can you initiate from the Job scheduler on IBM i?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Is it really telnet or do you simply want to check if a port is open?

Comment: The aim is to ensure a port on a remote connection is available 

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Albert York's [TNAPI](http://www.albertyork.yolasite.com/samples.php) project...

TNAPI - An API that allows batch programs to run interactive commands and programs and RUNTNSCR a utility that runs scripts using TNAPI

Another option might be the [virtual terminal APIs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/apis/vt1a.htm) built into the OS...